# Why would I use a where constraint that restricts to only a single type?

Tags: c#

So I was looking at the MSDN example here: [Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and the 1st example shows the following generic class defining a `where` constraint with a single concrete type: `Employee`

```
public class GenericList<T> where T : Employee
```

Now when using a `where` constraint I totally understand the use when defining > 1 type, *or* most certainly when using an Interface. However (and I know it was only an example), why would I ever want to just use a `where` constraint to restrict to a single concrete type? Couldn't I just replace the code below:

```
public T FindFirstOccurrence(string s)
```

with the following since there is only a *single constraint* anyway?

```
public Employee FindFirstOccurrence(string s)
```

The only reason I could see deploying code with a single `where` constriant is for flexibility in the future to add additional constraints for if `Employee` became `IEmployee` and I was set up a bit easier for the changes.

Can someone explain what purpose using a `where` constraint for a single type provides?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> why would I ever want to just use a where constraint to restrict to a single concrete type?

Not quite right there - the constraint is on the `Employee` type and any type that inherits from it, so it can apply to `Manager` and `CEO` classes as well.

Defining the constraint means you can use any accessible methods on the `Employee` type inside your code, whether the passes in type is an `Employee` or an inheriting type.

Comment: If the method was non-generic and just returned an `Employee` you could still return a `Manager` or a `CEO` and utilize whatever `Employee` publicly exposes, and have polymorphic behavior.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common pattern you see with fluent interfaces.  Consider the following example code:

```
public class Employee {}
public class Manager : Employee{}

public static T Method<T>(T employee) where T : Employee
{
    //do some stuff with the employee
    return employee;
}
```

Now when calling the method we can do:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee = Method(employee);

Manager manager = new Manager();
manager = Method(manager);
```

If we just returned an `Employee` instead of `T` then this second method call would return an `Employee`, but here it *returns a* `Manager`.  We avoid upcasting the type while still maintaining static typing.  There are other situations in which it's useful as well, but that underlying principle is a common use of generics.

Answer (score 1):

The type T is a generic one and as you said it could probably be an interface or a base class. This means that, besides flexibility and other stuff like that, you can insert other classes that implement/extend the interface/base class. So type T could practically mean multiple classes.

Let's say that T is a base class `Shape`, so `Square`, `Rectangle` and `Triangle` extend `T`. When you have the constraint with `T` you can practically inject or a `Square`, `Rectangle`, or `Triangle` and each of them have their own implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose is for the compiler to know what method/property signatures can be used in the generic implementation.

Consider this:

```
public class Employee{
     public string Name{get;set;}
     public double Salary{get;set;}
}

public class Manager : Employee{
    public List<Employee> Manages{get;set;}
}

public class PayrollList<T> : List<T> where T:Employee{
    public void SendOutPeriodPay(){
    // Note that employee.Name and .Salary are accessible 
    // even if the list is of Manager type
        this.ForEach(employee=>PaySystem.SendPay(employee.Name,employee.Salary));
  }
}
```